# Winter Bash 2013

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It's that time of year again.  Last year, we participated in [Winter Bash 2012](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/winter-bash-2012).

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".  For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: hats]

This year, SE is expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate.  This event will run from **16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014**.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat **will have an "I hate hats" option** available, just as we had last year.

The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

So, **does Drupal Answers want to participate**?  Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

[image]

Comment: Please vote on the question: +1 for yes and -1 for no

Comment: interesting I want hat!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Who could hate hats? :(

Comment: I am also interesting.

Comment: Not a single downvote, so when do we start? First snow was today, here where I live ;)

Comment: @Mołot we need to wait till December 16, anyway enjoy your first day snow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I just told the SE team that we want to do this.

Comment: @Mołot don't forget to check your rank here http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com and here http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Answer (score 5):

It is simply an amazing concept / event to introduce hats and i have few reasons to advocate my statement:

1. It gears up the enthusiasm in the community.
2. It adds flavor to celebration. Especially, I just love to flaunt my hats.
3. It integrates a pinch of mystery to uncover a new hat on regular activity on community.
4. Just read above comments for god-sake. Its all Yes Yes Yes....

Answer (score 2):

Drupal Answers can sometimes look a bit stiff for newbies, so, yeah, why not? Cheering up the website for a while sounds fun!