# Winter Bash 2014

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It's that time of year again.  Last year, we participated in [Winter Bash 2013](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/winter-bash-2013).

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".  For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: hats]

This event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2014.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So, **does Drupal Answers want to participate**?  Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

[image]

Comment: last year ranked #2nd http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ooops link broken @MPD http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bala This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015.

Comment: yeah I doubt that!!

Comment: @Bala That URL is copy/paste from the email I got yesterday about this.

Comment: Would the hats earned in 2013 still be in our hat collection? Or do would we start with a blank slate?

Comment: @Jance Pretty sure it is a blank slate.

Comment: I would love to participate this year :)

Comment: @Bala c'mon, beat me this year ;) Oh, I wanna be unicorn again...

Comment: Community user has got 9 hats. Lol

Comment: Any gifts for those who collects more hats ;)

Comment: @arun isn't fame enough? :D

Comment: [featured] can be removed and [status-completed] added, since the Dec 1 deadline has passed.

Comment: Again 2nd place @Mołot http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I let SE know that we want our hats.

Comment: Yay, spammers need hats too!

Comment: @bjb568 wait, what? :/

Comment: @Mołot I'm commenting about the unusually high amount of spam on drupal, perhaps only beaten by meta.SE.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=drupal&Room=89&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest