# Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It's that time of year again.  Last year, we participated in [Winter Bash 2014](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/winter-bash-2014).  Hopefully, by adding this sentence, I can make this different enough to trick the system to not detect it as an exact duplicate question as last years'.

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".  For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: hats]

This event will run from **14 December 2015** to **3 January 2016**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2015.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So, **does Drupal Answers want to participate**?  Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I won't this year, but have fun everybody.

Comment: The image is too old, now. Remind me of taking a picture for this year, so we can use it. `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno You can find a few screenshots here: http://stackexchange.com/promos

Comment: @Molot we had fun for past 2 years, hope this year too!!!

Comment: I wouldn't see why not. There is an easy opt-out and hats are a sort of achievements that are often easier to acquire then medals. They motivate me to perform that extra action on that particular day.

Comment: @Mołot are you serious? won't you participate this year :( . Okay at least help us to get some hats this year too  ;). but it would be fun if you participate

Comment: @KrishnaMohan No time, sorry. E way to busy in c# :( working overtime.

Comment: @kiamlaluno , reminder  ;) dashboard page is ready at http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard .

Comment: The hats this year are "meh". I wish they were like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/QOZfx.jpg

Comment: Is it just a game? what the winner will get?

Comment: It's just a fun feature. Winner will get nothing but fun. ;) :P

Answer (score 4):

I never had read about this in the SE Community.

At the end we can make a contest to select the user that looks more funny with his/her hat!

Answer (score 4):

Can't wait for this years!

I was at the first place at the time the event closed. There were 757 users, earning 1,113 hats.

I really liked the last years one, with rotatable and resizable hats, and really clever objectives. Hopefully this year would be even more awesome. Good luck everyone!

[image: leaderboard]

[image: my hats]

Comment: I scored 2nd for past 2 years hope this year have fun too, cheers!! Thankfully screenshot show's my profile too

Comment: I wish I had a screenshot with all people, but I took this on a tab, and couldn't take a full-length one.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds fun! Let's do it! I've never done this before...

Answer (score 3):

Yes ! I am waiting to get this treasure.

Can anybody please put the link that explaining event rules and other details of the event.

Comment: I believe winterbash2015.stackexchange.com will have all of the rules and details closer to when it starts.

Comment: Thanks @MPD. We will wait to starts.. :)

Comment: Finally day comes to rock.....

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan, and have been looking forward to this! Lets do it!