# Winter Bash 2016

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It's that time of year again.  Last year, we participated in [Winter Bash 2015](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/winter-bash-2015).  This is not a duplicate yet.  Each year we have gauge interest.  Once the event is over, we will close it as a duplicate.

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".  For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: hats]

This event will run from **19 December 2016** to **8 January 2017**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2016.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So, **does Drupal Answers want to participate**?  Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

[screenshot http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/promos/winter-bash-2014/2.jpg](http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/promos/winter-bash-2014/2.jpg)

Comment: I want chritmas & New year gift this year too!!

Comment: feels like it was yesterday that I read the [Winter Bash 2015](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/winter-bash-2015)

Comment: @NoSssweat Probably has nothing to do with the fact that the question has been copy-pasta since the 2013 version...

Comment: I'd like to ! Even if this is maybe, somehow "kitsch", it gives a touch of fun & festive season...

Comment: To the person who voted to close as a duplicate: this is not a duplicate yet. Each year we have gauge interest. Once the event is over, we will close it as a duplicate.

Comment: 4 days to go!!!.. I scored **1st** last year. But I can't participate this year. I'll try to help others to get hats ;) Have Fun everyone ;)

Comment: past 3 years scored 2nd, i doubt about this year

Comment: @KrishnaMohan is there a Drupal hats leader board?

Comment: yes @NoSssweat here you go - For DA - http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can find entire hats here Ofcourse not the secret ones ;) - http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Congrats to @AdrianCidAlmaguer for winning this year.

Comment: @mpdonadio aren't you forgetting something? cough, cough...

Comment: @NoSssweat We normally get an email from the CM team about it.  I guess they are just assuming all sites are in now.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Drupal Answers wants to participate in Winter Bash 2016!

[image]

([Santa hat source](http://www.ross.ws/content/drupal-night-christmas))